# Payment gateways are not synced

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce2, stripe

```
Craft Solo : 3.1.25
Craft Commerce : Lite (2.1.12.1)
```

I am trying to integrate it with Commerce Lite for a subscription plan.

- I Created 1 product at stripe account.
- Added stripe keys to my local store.
- Payment is working in test mode. ( so keys are correct)

[image]

In settings/subscriptions/plans i created 1 plan but not getting any gateway plans ( i am assuming craft will fetch the product created on stripe so that i can link them with craftstore subscriptions)

All the stripe products are fetched.

[image]

After reloading the page gateway changed to Plan name ( website subscription plan)

[image]

What i am missing ?

Update: I created a gif on the issue.

https://we.tl/t-zluYdB3dzg

Comment: Are you getting any JS errors in your browser's console?  If you check your browser's network tab when you hit "refresh" what does the response come back as?

Comment: @BradBell No there are no js errors in console admin panel .

Comment: @BradBell please see the GIF in my question